# Pass array of int in Angular Route

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Well, I did some research before asking this question.

This is my path

```
{ path: 'cart/:productIds', component: CartComponent }
```

I want to pass productIds when click on cart like below in AppComponent. Can I do this ?

```
 goToCart() {
this.router.navigate(['/cart', this.productIds]);}
```

Am trying to access these productIds in ngOnit in cartcomponent like this

```
this.productIds = route.snapshot.params["productIds"];
```

My question is, Is this the efficient way of passing and accessing array of Int between two components?

how do we maintain state(not sure whether this is right word, my background is ASP.NET) between components ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a **`service`** to save the array of ids from one component to other component. It's not a safe way to pass it over the url.

Create a service like this,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class AppMessageQueuService {

    myIds: Array<Number>=[];
    constructor() {

    }
    saveIds(produIds:any){
        this.myIds = produIds;
    }
    retrieveIDs(){
        return this.myIds;
    }

}
```

Then you can inject this Service into both the components and save it from the first component like,

```
this.appMsgService.saveIds(yourIds);
```

then retrieve in the second component as,

```
this.appMsgService.retrieveIDs(yourIds);
```

you can inject to your component as,

```
constructor(
   private appMsgService: AppMessageQueuService
)
```